# All of a sudden reputation changed from ~7000 to ~7300. How is this possible?

Tags: support, reputation

Today morning when I logged in to Ask Ubuntu, all of a sudden my reputation points changed from ~7000 to ~7300 but there are no traces. How is this possible?

How can I trace these reputation changes?
Also I was getting reputation +5 for a Question up voted to me. But I am getting +10 roughly after reaching 7000 reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Global Rep Adjustment.

Read ["We're rewarding the question askers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) on the StackOverflow blog for details.  They started implementation yesterday.  (Upvotes on questions that were +5 are now +10 so you gain rep from this recalc)

Mods have more details on this than end users do, though, so I'll include this tidbit specific for your reputation for this inquiry only:

> Global Recalc: question upvote value change old rep = 7024, new rep = 7364 by Community

(this is moderator-visible only in the tools, which is where I got this from.  Everyone has a similar entry if they've posted any question that's gotten upvotes on the site.)

Comment: I was beaten by Thomas in posting the answer by a minute. Now I know, *Mods have more details on this than end users do*.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I was trying to catch up with foss, but a couple of days ago I noticed he was now behind me by more than 20K points. So I first thought it was a horrible issue with askubuntu. Since the kids were sick the whole week I was not able to find out what happened, but now I see it was this.

Answer (score 5):

This is because network wide reputation recalculation occurred last night. Earlier an upvote on question used to award +5 reputation points but since yesterday it would award +10 (equal to an upvote on answer). The change was made retroactively, i.e., the reputation was awarded as if it was always +10. You can have a look on [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/reputation) page.

You must have a total 60 upvotes on questions, thus adding extra 300 (5*60) points.
 For more info, read the [blog post by Sara Chipps](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1).